# How should I detach those kinds of components on my motherboard?

Tags: connector, components, motherboard

How should I detach both components linked by white, blue and red wires from the computer motherboard on the attached picture?

Just pulling them?

Indeed, I don't want to damage them.

[image: Motherboard]

Comment: the technique to remove those kind of components from PCB is called de-soldering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid pulling on the wires. Pulling on the plug body will be hard, use a screwdriver or fingernails around the edge of it.